# Ansible: Error while passing numeric only value as user name to user module

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

While passing numeric only value as user name to user module an error is thrown "invalid user".

```yaml
- name: "Create User Task"
    user: 
      name: "'{{ item.user }}'"
      state: present
    with_items: 
      - user: user1
      - user: user2
      - user: 333
```

But passing as alphanumeric like "uuu" getting passed.

Please help how i can pass numeric value to get success.

Comment: name: "Create User Task"
      user: 
        name: "‘{{ item.user }}’"
        state: present
      with_items: 
        - 
          user: user1
        - 
          user: user2
        - 
          user: 333

Comment: You may have a look into [What characters should I use or not use in usernames on Linux?](https://serverfault.com/a/578264/448950), [Why can't Linux usernames begin with numbers?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287077/) or [All-numeric usernames in Red Hat Enterprise Linux](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3103631).

Answer (score 0):

This seems not to be an Ansible Issue itself and not related to programming at all but to the operating system, see

- [What characters should I use or not use in usernames on Linux?](https://serverfault.com/a/578264/448950)
- [Why can't Linux usernames begin with numbers?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287077/)
- [All-numeric usernames in Red Hat Enterprise Linux](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3103631)

And even if it is possible to have numeric only user names under some circumstances, there will be other restriction later as in Ansible Issue #66544 "*[`file` module wrongly interprets numeric username as UID](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/66544)*".

> At minimum this seems to be non-intuitive behavior that should be documented. It is perfectly POSIX "legal" to have usernames that are integers.

> We don't plan to add support for this, but should document it.